# How to solve NaN and Invalid error in Fortran

Tags: fortran, nan

My outputs are all NaN, and the standard error is "IEEE_INVALID_FLAG". I debug the code in gdb and find that the line that IEEE_INVALID_FLAG first happens is line 281:

```
Program received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
0x000055555555c830 in calcu () at SIMPLE-2D.f:281
281      &      +(1.-URFU)*U(I,J)
```

The code for line 281 is an expression for
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZaeD.png), and the complete code is:

```
      U(I,J)=URFU/APU(I,J)*
     &      (AEEU(I,J)*U(I+2,J)+AEU(I,J)*U(I+1,J)
     &      +AWWU(I,J)*U(I-2,J)+AWU(I,J)*U(I-1,J)
     &      +ANNU(I,J)*U(I,J+2)+ANU(I,J)*U(I,J+1)
     &      +ASSU(I,J)*U(I,J-2)+ASU(I,J)*U(I,J-1)
     &      +(P(I,J)-P(I+1,J))*DY)
     &      +(1.-URFU)*U(I,J)
```

I=1:79,J=1:80. AEEU,AEU,... are 79*80 matrix.
Could anyone can give me some idea about this error? Many thanks!

Comment: What compiler are you using?  All of the compilers that I have in the recent past have several options to help with your problem.  What options have you used.

Comment: Impossible to tell from what you have said. If U is a (1:79,1:80) array and I and J cover the ranges you say you are accessing then you are making out of bounds array accesses. Or apu( i, j ) could be zero - which may be due to a bug elsewhere in the code. As a first step turn on all run time checks and see what gets flagged.

Comment: @evets I use gfortran as compiler and gdb as debugger.

Comment: @IanBush Thanks. I use `gfortran -fbacktrace -fcheck=all -Wall Mycode.f -o mycode` to compile the code, and the code can run but all the outputs are NaN. After the iterations finish, the compiler shows that `Note: The following floating-point exceptions are signalling: IEEE_INVALID_FLAG IEEE_OVERFLOW_FLAG IEEE_UNDERFLOW_FLAG IEEE_DENORMAL`. And as I mentioned above, I use gdb to find the IEEE_INVALID_FLAG first happens ate line 281, but I cannot find the reason... Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Add `-ffpe-trap=invalid` to your command line.  This should cause your executable to trap on the first instances of an NaN.  I suspect your line 281 may not be the place the actual error starts as NaN will propagate.

Comment: @evets Thanks! I use the command gfortran `-g -ffpe-trap=invalid mycode.f -o mycode` to compile code, and `gdb mycode` to debug code. The results show that `Program received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
0x000055555555c871 in calcu () at mycode.f:281
281      &      +(1.-URFU)*U(I,J)` I think line 281 is the location that ` INVALID` error first happens but I really don't know how to solve it. I have stuck here for 2 weeks... I would be very appreciated if you could give my any help! Many thanks!

Comment: We need the source and the values of the variables when the NaN occurs.  Either one of the entities is an NaN or your numerator and denominator are both zero.

Comment: I would add a print before line 281 to get the values of the variables involved in the equation. It looks like the invalid values come from somewhere before line 281. Check also for uninitialized variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time, NaNs result from operations on infinities, e.g., Infinity * 2 = NaN. As suggested by the compiler output, you have both **overflow** and **underflow**. Overflow happens when the variable type cannot contain the number because the exponent is positive and too big (very large number), and underflow happens when the number is too small because the exponent is negative and too big (very small number). Try changing your code to use double precision real. In FORTRAN 77, this can be achieved using the `DOUBLE PRECISION` type:

```
DOUBLE PRECISION URFU
DOUBLE PRECISION U(:,:)
```

In modern Fortran, you can use something like this:

```
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: dp = KIND(1.D0)
REAL(KIND=dp) :: URFU, U(:,:)
```

Comment: @Ken White Hi, Ken, I am very sorry to post a too board question "OpenFOAM C++ coding" recently https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75013935/openfoam-c-coding. I just start learning c++ when using OpenFOAM, so I apologize if I ask bad questions. Unfortunately, my account does not allow to post new questions. So I follow the guide to improve my existing questions. I delete a few questions posted long before and with few replies (0 vote). And for this -3 vote question, I accept the answer from wyphan. Could you please let me know what else can I do to lift the ban of my account? Thanks!